# Error in fit method of scikit learn chain classifier with a keras model for a multilabel problem

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I'm building a chain classifier for a multiclass problem that uses KerasClassifier model. I have 17 labels as classification target and shape of X_train is (111300,107) and y_train is (111300,17) My code is here:

```
def create_model():
  input_size=length_long_sentence
  embedding_size=128
  lstm_size=64
  output_size=len(unique_tag_set)
    #----------------------------Model -------------------------------
  current_input=Input(shape=(input_size,)) 
  emb_current = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=input_size)(current_input)
  out_current=Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size))(emb_current )
  #out_current = Reshape((1,2*lstm_size))(out_current)
  output = Dense(units=len(unique_tag_set), activation='softmax')(out_current)
  model = Model(inputs=current_input, outputs=output)
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  print(model.summary())
  return model

   model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1,batch_size=256)
   print(type(model))
   chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
   history=chain.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The Model summary is here:

[image]

When tried to ti use the fit method on ClassifierChain, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any one can guide me about this error and what is (None,2)?

Comment: I think softmax doesnt fit with multi label setting, which is the case for chainclassifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documention of chain classifier:

> A multi-label model that arranges binary classifiers into a chain.

Hence convert your keras model as binary classifier using a single node in final layer and loss function as binary_crossentropy

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes you are right. by changing the keras model as binary classifier, the chain classifier is now working.

Comment: Glad that I'm  able to help u. Could you accept the answer?

Comment: I'm getting warnings while training as the input shape is (none,107), while in chain classifier, binary classifiers are linked in chain and one binary classifier output is used as input in next binary classifier so for next binary classifier, the input shape would be (none,108) and so on.

Comment: @Aizayousaf I was running into the same problem, If i have six label then how to set the dimension of my y_train ?
thank you

Comment: Do you want to use chain classifier?